# Update enabled migration module

Tags: migrations

I enabled a migration module. Now I would like to make some changes inside the yml file. How can I update my migration? 
I use  migration plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a partial configuration import and then a cache rebuild

```
drush cim --partial --source=modules/custom/MY_MIGRATION_MODULE/config/install -y
drush cr
```